# Wordpress:Page Title Appears twice

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am in the process of setting up my own e-commerce website powered by wordpress and woocommerce but i have come up against some issues.

Specifically when i click on a product category the page title bar appears twice and i have been trying to eliminate this issue.Whereas the shop page is behaving correctly,only spawning the page name only once.

What i have done so far is:

1. Disabled the yoast SEO wordpress plugin(read somewhere that it might be the issue).Nothing happened.
2. Tried to edit the style.css by adding the class"page-title" of the bar that appears twice and using the display:none feature.The bar disappeared but the other bar did as well since they share the same exact path and class as the one in the shop page.

The proper format of the page is located here - www.survivalmotion.com/shop/
The one that has the issues is any product category such as  - http://www.survivalmotion.com/product-category/backpacks/
The topbar is the one i want to eliminate.

Any idea on how should i proceed to fix this?

Comment: Clearly, there's something wrong with your template.  Switch to a different theme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.main-content-inner-full>.page-title{display:none;}
.main-content-inner>.page-title{display:block !important}
```

Comment: This is just a band-aide for a broken template.